# Adding variables to conjoint

Tags: regression, probit, conjoint-analysis

Could you please help me with conjoint analysis. 
I would like to conduct choice based conjoint. I have created attributes and levels of the product. 
My dependent variable is willingness to pay. So my equation is

*Willingness to pay = b*attr1 + b*attr2....*

And everything is clear for me n
However, I have a problem. 
I want to add some extra variables in my equation. (Emotions of the respondents). 
Thus, I want to measure respondents' emotions after they watch ads, then conduct choice based conjoint.( show profiles with attributes and ask respondents to choose) 
As a result, my equation will be

*Willingness to pay = b * attr1 + b * attr2.... + b * emotions*.

Is it possible to do that? Will it negatively influence my results or not?

Comment: You're describing a contingent valuation exercise, not a conjoint analysis.  You can use the model you described, and you may want to think about interacting the emotion variable with the attribute parameters to understand which attributes are more affected by emotion.  I'm not clear though, how you intend to parametrize emotion.